# Missing PaperClip Image (RoutingError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The images that I upload don't show when I use the paperclip gem. I get this error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/handyman_imgs/handyman_index/missing.png")

This is what I have:

**Controller File**

```
class HandymenController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_handyman, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:profession].blank?
      @handymen = Handyman.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @profession_id = Profession.find_by(name: params[:profession]).id
      @handymen = Handyman.where(:profession_id => @profession_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end 
  end

  def show
  end 

  def new
    @handyman = current_user.handymen.build
    @professions = Profession.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }
  end

  def create
    @handyman = current_user.handymen.build(handyman_params)
    @handyman.profession_id = params[:profession_id]

    if @handyman.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end 

  def edit
    @professions = Profession.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }
  end

  def update
    @handyman.profession_id = params[:profession_id]
    if @handyman.update(handyman_params)
      redirect_to handyman_path(@handyman)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @handyman.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def handyman_params
    params.require(:handyman).permit(:name, :location, :phone_number, :profession_id, :handyman_img)
  end 

  def find_handyman
    @handyman = Handyman.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**Model File**

```
class Handyman < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession

  has_attached_file :handyman_img, styles: { handyman_index: "250x350>", handyman_show: "325x475>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :handyman_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**ErrorLog**

```
Started GET "/handyman_imgs/handyman_index/missing.png" for ::1 at 2016-08-15 10:29:24 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/handyman_imgs/handyman_index/missing.png"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (106.1ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (332.3ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (216.2ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (335.3ms)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking about? What is the problem and how have you try to solve it?

Comment: the images that i upload cant display when i use the paperclip gem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question based on what you wrote in comments, and added the error message from the error log at the top, as it seems essential. It is helpful that you included the code and errorlog.